# Define static file directory per route (URL) in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, static-files

I have several files: `1.html`, `2.html`, etc. which have this content:

1.html has

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="1-directory/image.jpg" />
```

2.html has

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="2-directory/image.jpg" />
```

etc.

So, every file has an image in `<i>-directory/` (`i` varies: 1, 2, 3, ...).
How can I load this images in flask for every file.

My route is:

```
@app.route('/docs/show/<int:i>')
def show(i):
    with open(i + '.html', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        return render_template('show.html', content = content)
```

and my template `show.html` is

```
{content | safe}
```

So, I want to set `<i>-directory` in the flask for each file and so displaying the corresponding image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the static folder and then you have to add all the folders with the image. You can follow this directory structure:

```
PROJECT NAME
>> static
  >> 1-directory
      >> 1.jpg
  >> 2-directory
      >> 2.jpg
  >> 3-directory
      >> 3.jpg
  >> 4-directory
      >> 4.jpg
>> templates
  >> 1.html
  >> 2.html
  >> 3.html
  >> 4.html
  >> show.html
>> venv folder
>> app.py
```

You can use this code for **app.py**:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/docs/show/<string:i>', methods=['GET'])
def show(i):
    with open('templates/' + str(i) + '.html', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
    return flask.render_template('show.html', content = content)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0',port=<your_port_name>)
```

You can keep the **1.html** as below:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="/static/1-directory/1.jpg" />
```

You can keep the **2.html** as below:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="/static/2-directory/2.jpg" />
```

You can keep the **3.html** as below:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="/static/3-directory/3.jpg" />
```

You can keep the **4.html** as below:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="/static/4-directory/4.jpg" />
```

And, you can display your code in **show.html** (with the same way you have shown it):

```
<html>
<body>{{content | safe}}</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT (As per your comments):**

I have created the file structure in the following way as per your comments:

```
PROJECT NAME
>> templates
  >> 1-directory
      >> 1.jpg
  >> 2-directory
      >> 2.jpg
  >> 3-directory
      >> 3.jpg
  >> 4-directory
      >> 4.jpg
  >> 1.html
  >> 2.html
  >> 3.html
  >> 4.html
  >> show.html
>> venv folder
>> app.py
```

You can code for **app.py** like this:

```
@app.route('/docs/show/<string:i>', methods=['GET'])
def show(i):
    internal_html = flask.render_template(str(i)+'.html', file_name = str(i)+'-directory/'+str(i)+'.jpg')
    return flask.render_template('show.html', content = internal_html)

@app.route('/serve_file/<path:filename>')
def serve_file(filename):
    return flask.send_from_directory('templates/', filename)
```

All your **HTML** files will be as shown below:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img src="{{ url_for('serve_file', filename=file_name) }}" />
```

Also, your **show.html** will be the same as the above code.
Here, we are using this **send_from_directory**, because the flask does not serve other than /static folder. Thus, for external use of the folder, we have to use **send_from_directory**.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I have in the same directory, files and static ones. Something like: `ls docs`: `1.html, 1-directory/1.jpg, 2.html, 2-directory/2.jpg` I can create symbolic links to directories to have `static` dir, but it's tedious!

Comment: Please check the `EDIT` part, I have checked the code and it is working fine for me. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Can I use `<img src="/templates/filename" />` instead of `<img src="{{ url_for('serve_file', filename=file_name) }}" />`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way that this can be done "in flask". I can think of a couple of ways you would want to do this by hand anyways (validation, authorization, security).

But to answer the question, there are several ways you could go about it, depending on how "magical" you want the solution to be. (I assume that if you want flask to handle it, then you want magic)

One solution would be a decorator that injects the loaded snippet into the view function as a new parameter.

```py
import functools

def inject_snippet(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(i, *args, **kwargs):
        filepath = f"{i}-directory/{i}.html"
        with open(filepath) as f:
            snippet = f.read()
            return func(snippet, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@app.route('/docs/show/<int:i>')
@inject_snippet
def show(snippet):
    return render_template('show.html', content=snippet)
```

Comment: But how does it work really? How this code display image `i-directory/image.jpg`? `f"{i}-directory/{i}.html"` is really `{i}.html`?

Comment: Error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{i}/{i}.html'`. My code is [here](https://pastebin.com/6ZsRjnNH) and my files are [here](https://pastebin.com/VpfEL4jr)